# Checking if a list of files exists before proceeding?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some pandas code running for 9 different files each day. Currently, I have a scheduled task to run the code at a certain time but sometimes the files have not been uploaded to the SFTP by our client on time which means that the code will fail. I want to create a file checking script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import os, time

filelist = ['file1','file2','file3']

while True:
    list1 = []

    for file in filelist:
        list1.append(os.path.isfile(file))

    if all(list1):
        # All elements are True. Therefore all the files exist. Run %run commands
        break
    else:
        # At least one element is False. Therefore not all the files exist. Run FTP commands again
        time.sleep(600) # wait 10 minutes before checking again
```

all() checks if all the elements in the list are `True`. If at least one element is `False` it returns `False`.

Answer (score 10):

Shortening Farhan's answer.  You can use list comprehension and be extra fancy to simplify the code.

```
import os, time
while True:
   filelist = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
   if all([os.path.isfile(f) for f in filelist]):
      break
   else:
      time.sleep(600)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another much simpler approach using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```py
import os

file_names_list = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

if all(list(map(os.path.isfile,file_names_list))):
   # do something
else:
   # do something else!
```